How do I authenticate ASP.NET Framework Web API using Keycloak and jwt tokens?
When I search internet for Keycloak authentication for .NET, I get hundreds of examples for .NET Core Web API, but for .NET Framework Web API I am yet to get a complete article. I wish to implement client credentials grant for .net framework Web APIs because it is program to program communication, with no user involved. I am a newbie in OAuth, OpenID Connect and OWin. A detailed step by step guidance is what I am looking for. Could you please provide me one or point me to some good links. Keycloak is the OAuth server of choice in our company and it is mandatory to use Keycloak for all authentication needs.
I created an Owin Startup class for my project and added the following configuration :
       app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
       new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
       {
             AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
             Realm = "https://staging.com/auth/realms/drugdev",
             TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
             {
                   ValidateIssuer = true,
                   ValidateAudience = true,
                   ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                   ValidIssuer = "https://staging.com/auth/realms/drugdev", //some string,  
                   ValidAudience = "irt-api",
       
              }
           });

I always get HTTP 401 response when I try to call any Web API decorated with [Authorize] attribute.

I found a way without handling it in middlewares.
We can create a KeycloakAuthentication.cs file in the project like below
KeycloakAuthentication.cs
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Configuration; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Security.Claims; 
using System.Web; 
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt; 
using System.Security.Claims; 
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens; 
using System.Security.Cryptography; 
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters; 
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl; 

namespace Namespace.API.Common { 
    public class KeycloakAuthentication { 
        private static readonly string issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["issuer"]; 
        private static readonly string audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["audience"];
        //private static readonly string secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret"]; 
        // You might need to fetch the secret key from Keycloak if required. 
        private static readonly string secretKey = @"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----" +ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret"]+ "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"; 
        public static ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string token) { 
            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuer = true, 
            ValidIssuer = issuer, // Your Keycloak Realm URL 
            ValidateAudience = true, 
            ValidAudiences = new[] { "realm-management", "broker", "account", audience },
            // List all valid audiences 
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false, 
            IssuerSigningKey = GetRsaSecurityKeyFromKeycloakPublicKey(secretKey), 
            ValidateLifetime = true, 
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero }; 
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler(); try { SecurityToken validatedToken; return handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken); } catch (Exception ex) { // Handle token validation errors 
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
            return null; 
            } 
        } public static RsaSecurityKey GetRsaSecurityKeyFromKeycloakPublicKey(string publicKey) {
            try {
                var rsaKeyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters)
                new PemReader(new System.IO.StringReader(publicKey)).ReadObject(); 
                var rsaParameters = new RSAParameters { 
                    Modulus = rsaKeyParameters.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
                    Exponent = rsaKeyParameters.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned()
                    
                }; 
                    var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(); 
                    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters); 
                    return new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while creating the RSA key: {ex.Message}"); 
                throw;
            } 
        } 
    } 
}

After that you can add code in controller methods as below
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet] 
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/values/apiname/{param}")] 
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> apiname(string param){ 
        try { 
            bool IsOkForResponse = true; 
            string token = ""; 
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ISKEYCLOAKENABLED"] == "true") {
                HttpRequestMessage request1 = this.Request; 
                token = request1.Headers.GetValues("Authorization").FirstOrDefault().Split(' ')[1]; 
                var principal = KeycloakAuthentication.ValidateToken(token); 
                IsOkForResponse = (principal != null && principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated) ? true : false; 
                
            } 
            if (IsOkForResponse) { 
                //Your api functionality.
    }else{ 
        return Unauthorized() 
    }   
        }catch{ 
            return Unauthorized() 
        }
}

It will get you unauthorised if your access token is not valid.
Kindly setup all the things correct in web.config file as per configuration.
